# Cached Java Webstart App does not start

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have a Java app being deployed via Java Web Start. It creates Desktop shortcut on the first run.

A few users have complained that when they start the application(via the shortcut) the app fails to launch and they get this error.

Any idea what might be causing this?

This in on a shared computer with multiple users.

[image: Error Image]

Comment: May be users don't have enough privileges?

Comment: @Nambari - I found this a little hard to believe. Does Java have privilege issues like Databases do?

Comment: @Coffee: I mean user privileges at OS level, like read access to folder (or) cached folder no more exists etc.,

Comment: @Nambari-  Ok understood

Comment: @Nambari that may be possible but all the users in the company have the same windows imaged computers and by default have the same set of privelages. Only 2-3 people have reported this out of about 70-80 users.

Comment: @codeNinja: These users might did some cleanup? If possible, I will go to their machine and verify c:\users\....\AppData\LocalLow.... folder does really exists before spending any time on debugging further.